# How to write to partition /data files?

Tags: java, android, linux

**Hello everyone**

I have asked this question because I need to have write access to the files that my application will create using SuperUser commands in the `/data` partition (I do not create the files in the typical directory `/data/data` if not several), but My current code has not Given the desired result:

```
    public boolean creaArchivo2(String path, InputStream is)
    throws IOException {

    final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 4;

    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c mount -o remount,rw "+path);
    Process proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 "+path);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
    byte[] chunk = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
    int bytesLeidos = 0;

    while ( (bytesLeidos = is.read(chunk)) > 0) {

        os.write(chunk, 0, bytesLeidos);
    }
    os.close();

    return true;

}
```

**Explain my code**: My code all you do is try to set read and write permissions on the files that are in the partition / data and then copy the data in a conventional way with java, if instead of the error that apparently occur in the Commands could copy easily, but it does not work.

If they realize where I failed in my code or know another way to achieve my goal. Please let me know. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have root access on the phone you're attempting this on?

What exception do you get? You just said "it doesn't work". We need some more information, or we can't even attempt to help you.

If you're going to use root access and superuser commands, i'd recommend to use the RootTools library from Stericson:
https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools

It wraps all the complicated Process & Runtime stuff, and gives a usable API to also check for current root access, and much more.